# Cygwin: scp/ssh is slow

Tags: ssh, cygwin, scp, rdiff-backup

I'm using rdiff-backup for backuping my data. Since some machines are using Windows I installed sshd and rdiff-backup with cygwin there. The backup works but is pretty slow.
I then did some testing with scp, ssh copy over pipes, sftp and netcat between different systems. Between linux machines all is fine. Scp/ssh gives me about 70 MB/s. Over cygwin that speed drops down to about 8 MB/s. Using sftp or netcat gives good speeds though. I reach over 100 MB/s with netcat.

I tried using different ciphers and disabling compression. But that doesn't help. The machines are all recent ones with several gigs of ram and hardware raid. I tried it on different machines running cygwin and I get similar results.
Should I use netcat and tunnel it? That seems like a lot configuration overhead. Rdiff-backup can't use sftp as it seems so I'm out of luck here. I don't want to use sshfs either since rdiff-backup uses a rolling checksum and I don't want to transfer all data for calculation.

Any idea what's causing that slowdown?

**EDIT:**

Information about cygwin environment:

```
Windows 2008 Storage Server Standard Ver 6.0 Build 6002 Service Pack 2
CYGWIN_NT-6.0 filer 2.0.4(0.287/5/3) 2015-06-09 12:22 x86_64 Cygwin
openssh              6.8p1-1
```

**EDIT2**

When I enable verbose output for scp between Linux and Windows I get:

```
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 65536
```

The value is always the same for this transfer.

The same test between Linux and Linux gives me:

```
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 114688
```

Here the value differs from time to time and values like *131072* or *147456* appear.

Comment: I think cygwin on my machines are as fast as any other scp/sftp client but just in case I performed a test and got over 60MBs. Did you perform your test with sftp on the same windows machine? Cutting the speed below 10MBs usually means that your network adapter has negotiated at 100mbps instead of 1gbps. Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes, of course. I checked that. The link is at 1 Gbit and sftp gives me speeds around 100 MBs.
I just did another test with sftp and noticed there is a difference whether I start sftp on Windows and pull from Linux (around 100 MBs) and whether I start sftp on Linux and push to Windows (around 20 MBs). That's a bit weird. I can't see a difference using scp though. Both directions give me about 8 MBs here.